# Hide second and third row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, hide

```
<div class="NewsResultsList">   
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Results:<br/>
                First<br/>
                Second          
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No Results</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to hide the second row and the third row.

```
$('div.NewsResultsList table tr:eq(1)').hide(); 
$('div.NewsResultsList table tr:eq(2)').hide();
```

That didn't do it? What is wrong?

Comment: Place the div structure too, specially since it is used in the selector. I can't read minds.

Comment: Your question's code it is working *as is*. Was the issue really a typo?

Comment: Fix your `<td><td>` And... just a question: can happend that the First one needs to be hidden? I mean... when you need to hide the elements? Or you just need to strictly hide the last two?

Comment: So, you've used the edit feature to correct the two errors in your question that kept it from working.  So what's the remaining question?  It works as you have it now.

Comment: Voting to close.  After the latest edits to the question, there is no open question remaining and the OP has not responded to calls for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways to do it:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ipuyat/3/edit)*

```
$('.NewsResultList tr:gt(0)').hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr').slice(-2).hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr').not(':eq(0)').hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr td:contains("No")').parent('tr').hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr').not(':first').hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr').eq(-1).hide().end().eq(-2).hide();

$('.NewsResultList tr:last').prev().andSelf().hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {


            $('.NewsResultsList tr:eq(1)').hide();
            $('.NewsResultsList tr:eq(2)').hide();


        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You spelled `NewsResultList` wrong in your jQuery call. ("NewsResultsList")... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong selctors to get to that table rows:

It should actually be

```
$('div table tr:eq(1)').hide();
$('div table tr:eq(2)').hide();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bZPwE/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

You have `NewsResultsList` in your selector, but the class is `NewsResultList`.  The two don't match.

And, you are missing a `</td>` in the table.

Fix those two issues and it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pfemk/

Answer (score 0):

Try this for in your html/PHP:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Results:<br/>
                First<br/>
                Second          
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideMe">
            <td> </td>       
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideMe">
            <td>No Results</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this in your jQuery/javascript:

```
$('#something').click( function() {
    $('.hideMe').hide();
});
```

Comment: This is going in the wrong direction. **edit**: Nm, I'm stupid